# How to convert sample in AWS Lambda from javascript to Java?

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I currently am trying to convert this javascript sample:

**javascript**

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        callback(null, {"speech": "hello lambda js"});
};
```

**output from hitting test button in aws lambda**

```
{
  "speech": "hello lambda js"
}
```

Now I want to convert this in the simplest way into a Java program.

This is what I tried:

```
public class Sample implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

  @Override public String handleRequest(String s, Context context) {
    return "{\"speech\": \"hello lambda java\"}";
  }
}
```

but hitting the test button in AWS lamda complains:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",
  "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "stackTrace": [],
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@5f375618; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "errorType": "java.io.UncheckedIOException",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "cause": {
      "errorMessage": "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@5f375618; line: 1, column: 1]",
      "errorType": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
      "stackTrace": [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using your `Sample` class?

Comment: @SumnerEvans what do you mean? I have this class packaged up as a jar and deployed on aws lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript function is returning an object literal, not a JSON string.  Probably you need to do the parallel in Java, which would be to return an instance of a class that contains a property named speech, which a getter and setter for speech, and with the value of speech set to "hello lambda java".  AWS will probably take care of serializing that object to the JSON response you want.

More typing in Java than Javascript.  Ha!  I punned.

Comment: Hm. I'll give that a try.

AWS seems to do more magic than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense but send the method something like "hello", not JSON.  Lambda tries to be smarter than you and, if it sees something that looks like JSON it tries to parse it.  But then you ask for a string so it gets confused.  Personally I think this is a bug but since you can't pass a "Content-Type" it has to guess.

For reference, if I use this code:

```
public class HelloWorldLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    public String handleRequest(String inputObject, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("context logger - got \"" + inputObject + "\" from call");
        return "{\"speech\": \"hello lambda java\"}";
    }
}
```

and test with the string "hello" (yes, including the quotes) I get back what I expect in the Lambda test console.  If I send:

```
{
  "key3": "value3",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

I get the same error as you.